# Scene Builder combobox background color (inside)

Tags: css, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder, gluon

I am using Gluon [scenebuilder](/questions/tagged/scenebuilder) and I am making UI with lots of Comboboxes which are editable (important because the issue does not appear on non editable Comboboxes).
I need the combo box to be colored red (or any color does not matter) but when I use -fx-background-color and #a80808 in the style tab for my combobox, only the border of the box gets it reddish color.
as a clearance on the issue:
[scene builder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gEdY.png)

as a second related question to this one, I am also willing to change the color while the application is running so keep in mind I can not use a simple CSS code in my fxml file. I'm wondering how is that possible for this case (editable comboboxes).

Answer (score 0):

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VXPq.jpg)

```
-fx-color:red;
-fx-background-color:red;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that is not what i wanted, i need the white part (where you write the text) to be colorized.